# TeamCity, doesn't "find" the microsoft rule set on the build server, which results in warnings

Tags: c#, teamcity

I have created a warning tab in teamcity for a c# .Net solution using the following tutorial http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/enterprisedev/application-lifecycle-management/improved-teamcity-net-build-warnings/. It works, however I'm getting a warning for each project in the solution, as they are using rule sets.

I have configured the build in TeamCity to use the system environment variable "`CodeAnalysisRuleSet`" and specified the path to the installed rule sets (installed the static analysis tool, so didn't copy the files), however it says it can't find the rule set.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\Rule Sets\MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset".
```

Anyone, have a solution for getting TeamCity to use the rule set ?

Comment: And are you 100% certain that the file exists at that path? Can you execute the analysis from the command line on the build agent, basically do what TeamCity is doing, including running it under the same user account?

Comment: yes, I'm 100% that the file exists on the path, as if I copy paste it into a file explorer it wants to open the file...
I'm running it as a visual studio build, I don't know how TeamCity is doing it, but yes I guess I could.

Comment: If it says it can't find the file and the file definitely exists then the problem is almost certainly that the account the TeamCity build agent process is running under doesn't have access to that file. You've got a few options, run it under a different user, move the files to an accessible location, give the user account explicit access to that location.

Comment: @Nanhydrin thank you for taking your time, when I was going to look at the permission I found the problem, I was on the wrong build machine, emberassing.

Comment: we've all done it and it's a nice easy fix ;)